# Invoking custom tasks in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project with lot of sub-projects. Each sub project has its own build.gradle which contains the different tasks that needs to be run for that sub-project.

Some of the sub projects have their own specific tasks, not found in other sub projects.

Lets say sub project A has `taskA` and `taskB` as its specific tasks.

Issuing `gradle clean build taskA taskB` from the project A's directory invokes the tasks: `taskA`, `taskB`.

How can I modify the main `build.gradle` to invoke `taskA` and `taskB` when compiling sub-project A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the task dependencies for that. All you need is to make your task, which compiles your source, depending on this tasks. Let's assume, you have a `compile` task in your subproject, then all you need is to make this task depending on `taskA` and `taskB`, like:

```
compile.dependsOn taskA
compile.dependsOn taskB
```

It should be added into the build.gradle file root for subproject.

You can read about it in the [the official user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_dependencies)